# Rust: avoid duplicate "use" statements with local modules

Tags: rust

I might be using the wrong terminology here because I'm unfamiliar with Rust but essentially I'm trying to wrap a C library with safe Rust functions like this:

```
use std::os::raw::c_int;

mod c {
    use std::os::raw::c_int;

    #[link(name="math")]
    extern "C" {
        pub fn add(a: c_int, b: c_int) -> c_int;
    }
}

pub fn add(a: c_int, b: c_int) -> c_int {
    unsafe {
        c::add(a, b)
    }
}
```

I'm using `mod c` to avoid name clashes between the unsafe C functions functions and the safe Rust ones. Can I avoid retyping `use std::os::raw::c_int` somehow? This is just a minimal example, in reality there are many more of these duplicated `use` statements´.

Comment: You could `pub use` all your common imports in `c::types` or some other module, then import them with `c::types::*`

Comment: You can put `use super::*;` However, that will bring *everything* from the enclosing scope which may be confusing since your functions are named the same.